# Get all data from db which start with clicked letter, HTML, JS, PHP, MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

Trying to solve this up, I have to display all movies from db which start with clicked letter. By now I have collection.sql and db_collection.php which both work just fine. Also, doing all rendering from index.php (with few more lines in index.php below) works. But now I want to divide this on /gui part with index.html, app.js, style.css and /interface part with index.php and db_collection.php. So I would like to call index.php from app.js when each letter is clicked, with index.php check if there are movies for clicked letetr in db and then display all data from response in html.

Further, i'm not experienced with php at all, maybe I went totally wrong way from beginning.

gui/index.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="indexMovies()">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

gui/app.js

```
function indexMovies(){
    var c = document.getElementById('container');
    c.innerHTML = '';
    c.appendChild(header);
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
    alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
        var sign = document.createElement('a');
        sign.className = "node";
        sign.href = "index.html?sign="+letter;
        sign.onclick = get("index", letter);
        sign.innerHTML = letter;
        c.appendChild(sign);
        var border = document.createElement('span');
        border.innerHTML = " | ";
        c.appendChild(border);
    });
}
function get(addr, sign){
    var url = "../interface/" + addr + ".php?sign=" + sign;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what's the question about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think if this is an exercise is Ok, but you shouldn't use javascript to show the letters in an environment where PHP is available, has more much sense to use PHP because SEO and because how the user will saw the page. Always try to render the first version directly from server.

Saying that, I also think you should manage a JSON response from the PHP code. If you haven't tried, I would suggest learning about REST APIs and a PHP framework such as Laravel, it's ideal for this type of situations.
In this way, you really can accomplish your goal of keeping server code and interface code separated. So I would recode the PHP part like this:

```
<?php

include ("db_connection.php");

header("Content-type: application/json");

$sign = $_GET['sign'];
$rows = [];
/*
empty() checks for isset AND if variable is not null or '' or 0
otherwise if you ask for empty letter (can happen with a JS bug)
then you'll be returning all from database.
The other expression is for getting just one letter
to prevent SQL injection
*/
if (!empty($sign) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{1,1}$/",$sign)) {
  $queryTpl =
    "SELECT
      cover, title, relese_year, duration
    FROM
      movies
    WHERE
      title LIKE '".$sign."%'
    ORDER BY
      title";
  $result   = mysqli_query($db, $query_tpl);
  $rows     = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
echo json_encode($rows);

exit;
```

I suggest using jquery, for the sake of brevity I'll use it, if you know JS you'll not have any issues transforming this to it. So, the html would look like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the JS part like this (interface will have to go in the level up the HTML, you can solve this using routing if you want hide the PHP in server):

```
//try to keep things in your own scope
(function(){

  function indexMovies()
  {
    var c = document.getElementById('container');
    c.innerHTML = '';
    c.appendChild(header);
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
    alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
      var sign = document.createElement('a');
      sign.className = "node";
      sign.href = "index.html?sign="+letter;
      sign.onclick = get("index", letter);
      sign.innerHTML = letter;
      c.appendChild(sign);
      var border = document.createElement('span');
      border.innerHTML = " | ";
      c.appendChild(border);
    });
  }

  function get(addr, sign)
  {
    var url = "/interface/" + addr + ".php?sign=" + sign;
    $.ajax({
      'url': url
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
      var container = $('#container');
      var html = '<table>';
      if ( data.length==0 ) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>No movie with this start sign</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
      }
      else {
        for (var i in data) {
          html += buildMovieHtml(data[i]);
        }
      }
      html += '</table>';

      container.html(html);
    });
    return false;
  }

  function buildMovieHtml (element)
  {
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '  <td><img src="covers/'+ element.cover +'" height="278" width="185"</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '  <td>'+ element.title +' ('+ element.relese_year +')</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>Runtime: '+ element.duration +' min</td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    return html;
  }

})();
```

And you're done.

Comment: must do it in js, that is what exercise says. And cant use any ex library, pure js, php... and thanks i hope it'll help

Comment: Well, in that case the solution here it should work, just replace jQuery by plain javascript and you should be Ok.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sign.href = "index.html?sign="+letter;`

Also, you're returning the output of `get("index", letter);` to `sign.onclick`, instead wrap it in a function to assign the function the the onclick property.

```
sign.onclick = function() {
    get('index',this.textContent);
}
```

All together it will look like this

```js
function indexMovies(){
    var c = document.getElementById('container');
    c.innerHTML = '';
    c.appendChild(header);
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
    alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
        var sign = document.createElement('a');
        sign.className = "node";
        sign.onclick = function() {
            get('index',this.textContent);
        }
        sign.innerHTML = letter;
        c.appendChild(sign);
        var border = document.createElement('span');
        border.innerHTML = " | ";
        c.appendChild(border);
    });
}
```